# Using text replacement in a password field in iOS

Tags: ios, passwords

Using iOS 9, I have configured a common password that I always use when testing the app I'm working on for a common username/password login screen. Instead of having to type the password each time I had hoped to use the built-in text replacement functionality in iOS. I created the text replacement under General > Keyboard > Text Replacement and confirmed it worked in the Notes app. However, I can't get text replacement to work in the password field. I wanted to confirm this is by design and inquire as to why this is the case?

Another question: is there a way to get around this to have text replacement work or am I stuck having to type the password over and over again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's by design, because you're using secure text entry on the text field. In this mode the entered characters can't be seen, so any automatic changes would happen without the user knowing about it. That could leave someone in the position of not being able to login and not knowing why, because there password happened to overlap with an existing replacement.

You should just choose a short test password.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it had something to do with security but wasn't sure if there was an app that got around it.

Answer (score 1):

**Use macros for example;**

```
#ifdef DEBUG

self.passwordTextfield = @"password";

#endif
```

This will only be called when running in debug mode.